# Lutris error after apt-get update

Tags: 20.04, lutris

Started getting this error when trying to run a game via Wine through Lutris after running apt-get update and restarting my computer.

```
Error while completing task <bound method wine.prelaunch of <lutris.runners.wine.wine object at 0x7f78b5251040>>: <class 'AttributeError'> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/jobs.py", line 34, in target
    result = self.function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/runners/wine.py", line 819, in prelaunch
    self.setup_dlls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/runners/wine.py", line 776, in setup_dlls
    if dll_manager.version.lower() != "manual":
2022-04-30 12:36:05,162: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Putting this here for knowledge share!

The working solution I have is to comment out the following function in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/runners/wine.py`, like so:

```
    def setup_dlls(self, manager_class, enable, version):
        """Enable or disable DLLs"""
        # dll_manager = manager_class(
        #     self.prefix_path,
        #     arch=self.wine_arch,
        #     version=version,
        # )
        # # manual version only sets the dlls to native
        # if dll_manager.version.lower() != "manual":
        #     if enable:
        #         dll_manager.enable()
        #     else:
        #         dll_manager.disable()
        #
        # if enable:
        #     for dll in dll_manager.managed_dlls:
        #         # We have to make sure that the dll exists before setting it to native
        #         if dll_manager.dll_exists(dll):
        #             self.dll_overrides[dll] = "n"
```

This is obviously not a long term solution, but the game works in the mean time. - My question is: Does anyone have any ideas for a longer term solution/permanent fix?

Comment: What game? Where did you find this solution? Why isn't it a long term solution?

Comment: Any game using wine - for my purposes it's league of legends and all blizzard games. It's not a long term solution because it's commenting out some of the code that comes from Lutris - so it will get overwritten on the next update. Also, I dont know exactly what that code does, so I could be breaking something behind the scenes that is actually important

Comment: You're probably better off asking about this on lutris forums and support. Windows software is not designed to run on Linux and Lutris/Wine employ a lot of emulation and compatibility layers to get programs running. Generally the implementation is different per application. If you're having to do this on every application and nobody else has to do this, then I would try to determine what is different on your installation.